# How to display dynamic number of columns in Excel using axlsx (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I am using axlsx to generate excel reports

I would like a way to make add_row print out the columns in a collection dynamically.

So, say if I have a collection of records `@days` and based on some criteria, my collection can have varying number of columns (and rows as well).

So, if @days has 3 columns, I need to write this code:

```
sheet.add_row [@days[0].day, @days[1].day, @days[2].day]
```

and if it has 4 columns, I have to do this

```
sheet.add_row [@days[0].day, @days[1].day, @days[2].day, @days[3].day]
```

and if it has 5 columns, then I have to do this:

```
sheet.add_row [@days[0].day, @days[1].day, @days[2].day, @days[3].day, @days[4].day]
```

Is there a way to handle this dynamically and write just 1 line of code to handle all the above scenarios?

Please help!

Comment: `sheet.add_row @days.map(&:day)`

Comment: Thanks much! If I need to make the 1st 3 columns either nil or having hardcoded value, can I mix that with your code above?

Comment: That worked! Thanks much! Just one more related question. If I have columns named `day1, day2, day3, day4, day5` and based on some criteria, day4 and day 5 could be nil or just day5 could be nil. Is there a way to print only the non-nil columns? (If day 5 is nil, then ALL rows will have day5 as nil for sure)